# Bend SVG along spiral path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I have chain like this but longer. Can I somehow make it go along any path like spiral without changing it thickness and without making it into brush?

Comment: Why don't you want to make it into a brush?  That would be the easiest way to have a repeating pattern follow a curved path, such as a spiral.  If fact, probably the only practical way in Illustrator.

Comment: *Not* creating a brush just means you'll need to expend 500% more effort. Brush creation [isn't that difficult](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62068001#62068001). (I'm assuming you don't want a brush due to SVG compatibility - that doesn't mean you can't *create* as a brush then merely expand when you're ready to export the SVG file.)

Comment: @Scott I think when exporting to SVG, Illustrator will convert the brush to paths anyway. Using a brush should not really be a barrier to anything, and as you say, you can easily just expand the appearance if it is problem.